# How to know which "a" tag is clicked? AngularJs Way

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I've already searched about this question but their answer didn't solved mine so I created a new topic. I want to get the text of in the a tag i.e.(solo/partner).

This is what's inside my site.html:

```
<a href="#/app/partnerlistt" style="text-decoration:none">
     <div class="va-container">
          <div class="col va-btn"><b>partner</b></div>
          </div>
</a>


 <a href="#/app/sololist" style="text-decoration:none">
        <div class="va-container">
         <div class="col va-btn"><b>solo</b></div>
          </div>
 </a>
```

This is whats inside my controller.js:

```
var encodedString = 'action=' +
    encodeURIComponent("Showsomething") +
    '&position=' +
    encodeURIComponent("solo/partner");//this is where my clicked a tag should be passed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better using `$state` service provided by Angular `$state.go('state');`

Define your routes(recommended when you use SPA). Don't play with hardcoded hashes ever in AngularJS.

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider
      .state('partner', {
        url:'/app/partnerlistt',
        templateUrl: 'views/modals/partner.html'
      })
      .state('solo',{
        url:'/app/sololist',
        templateUrl: 'views/modals/solo.html'
      });
});
```

Have partner and solo html in a folder directory `views/modals`

HTML:

```
<a ng-click="navigateTo('partner')"  style="text-decoration:none">
</a>
<a ng-click="navigateTo('solo')" style="text-decoration:none">
</a>
```

Corresponding Controller: Inject `$state` service

```
$scope.navigateTo = function(to) {
  $state.go(to);
  var encodedString = 'action=' +
    encodeURIComponent("Showsomething") 
    + '&position=' +
    encodeURIComponent(to);
};
```

Comment: you have a good point.. but that state is inside my services.. so i just want the simplest thing on how to pass the word solo and partner, and since no need to change the href property in a tag

Comment: Inject the service in your controller and have a function in your service which returns the states. Now use the method like: `myService.getStates()` to retrieve states from service.

Comment: is it efficient if I just separate the controller of partner and solo? :D that's my only solution hahaha

Comment: Yea, separating views is always recommended in best practices. Every component should be a separate entity. If there's something common in both, use a service to share between. Hope the answer fulfils the question requirements :)

Comment: Would you like to mark it an answer or I would be willing to answer any more related doubts :)

Comment: they share something in common like the destination page of the a tag. nothing more,... that's I wanted to try doing it this way, but if I can't then i'll go with separating 2 controllers..

Answer (score 2):

In your html:

```
<a ng-click="go('partner')"  style="text-decoration:none">
</a>
<a ng-click="go('solo')" style="text-decoration:none">
</a>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.go = function(goTo) {
  // do the hash redirect
  window.location.hash = '#/app/' + goTo + 'list';
  // Here you can use the goTo parameter
  var encodedString = 'action=' +
    encodeURIComponent("Showsomething") 
    + '&position=' +
    encodeURIComponent(goTo);
}
```

---

Even better is when you dynamically load the links:

Controller:

```
$scope.links = ['solo', 'partner'];
```

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="link in links">
  <a ng-click="go(link)">
    {{link}}
  </a>
</a>
```

Comment: i'm trying it out.. i'll mark answer as soon as it solved my problem :)

Comment: it's giving me an error in data: encodedString,... ReferenceError: encodedString is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You can be done it with small changes in your code

```
<a ng-click="goTo('#/app/partnerlistt', 'partner');" style="text-decoration:none">
         <div class="va-container">
              <div class="col va-btn"><b>partner</b></div>
              </div>
    </a>


     <a  ng-click="goTo('#/app/sololist', 'solo');" style="text-decoration:none">
            <div class="va-container">
             <div class="col va-btn"><b>solo</b></div>
              </div>
     </a>
```

JS

```
$scope.goTo = funtion(url, type){
   console.log(type);
   $window.location.href= url;
};
```